A sequence of nonnegative numbers defined by three convergent sequences
Let $(a_n)_{n\ge 0}, (b_n)_{n\ge 0}, (c_n)_{n\ge 0}$ be sequences of nonnegative real numbers that are convergent to $a, b, c$, respectively, where $a\ne b$. Also let $(d_n)_{n\ge 0}$ be a sequence of nonnegative real numbers such that $a_n d_{n+1}+b_n d_n=c_n$ for every $n\ge 0$. Prove that the sequence $(d_n)_{n\ge 0}$ is convergent and find its limit.
What I am sure is that the limit of $(d_n)_{n\ge 0}$ must be equal to $\frac{c}{a+b}$ because this is what we get if we assume that the limit exists and we pass to the limit in the recurrence relation. What I have trouble doing is actually showing that $(d_n)_{n\ge 0}$ converges.
One thing that is easy to see is that $(d_n)_{n\ge 0}$ is bounded. Indeed, if $(d_n)_{n\ge 0}$ were not bounded, there would exist some subsequence of $(d_n)_{n\ge 0}$, call it $(d_{n_k})_{k\ge 0}$, such that $\displaystyle \lim_{k\to \infty} d_{n_k}=\infty$. Taking into account the nonnegativity of our sequences, we have $b_{n_k}d_{n_k}\le c_{n_k}$ and if we let $k\to \infty$ we reach a contradiction because $\displaystyle \lim_{k\to \infty}c_{n_k}=c\in [0, \infty)$.
Next my only idea was to try to show that $\displaystyle \liminf_{n\to \infty}d_n=\limsup_{n\to \infty}d_n$ because I thought that there is a chance this might work given the form of the recurrence relation. But since I don't know that $a>0$ or $b>0$ this is not really helpful, I can only show that $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} d_n\le \frac{c}{a+b}\le \limsup_{n\to\infty} d_n$$ by taking the limit inferior and superior in the reccurence relation.

Wouldn’t it be $a \neq - b$?

@julio_es_sui_glace well they are both limits of sequences of nonnegative real numbers, so $a\ne -b$ wouldn't really add anything. Anyway, I think I know where your question comes from: $a\ne b$ is enough to conclude that $a+b>0$ so that we can actually divide by $a+b$ for the limit.

You’re right. Would you manage obtaining something like $\lim \inf d_n \geq \frac{\lim \inf c_n}{\lim \sup a_n +b_n}$?

@julio_es_sui_glace hm, not really, because by taking the limit inferior/limit superior in the recurrence relation I could only get that chain of inequalities at the end of my post. Obtaining the inequality you mentioned would basically solve the problem.

It seems they are two cases regarding if $a >b$ or $a<b$

@julio_es_sui_glace interesting, this might be the case indeed. How did you approach it?

I’ve given a first part of answer, maybe you can manage to do the second part. I’m still thinking about it

@julio_es_sui_glace thank you, I will have a look at your answer and work on the second part too.

Done! You may check I often do mistakes ;)

Beware, your proof of boundedness is almost correct but does not deal with the case $b_n \to 0$. I’ll add a correction in my answer

See this Seems like a duplicate

Aparte: I’ll prove correctly the boundedness of $(d_n)_n$. We set $\delta_b = \inf_n b_b $ and $\delta_a = \inf_n a_n$. We also set $M = \sup_n c_n$.
Since $a_n d_{n+1} + b_n d_n = c_n$, we have $M \geqslant \delta_b d_n$ thus $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, d_n \leqslant \frac{M}{\delta_b}$ (with convention $\frac{1}{0} = \infty$.
Similarly we have $d_n \leqslant \frac{M}{\delta_a}$ so
$$d_n \leqslant \min \left( \frac{M}{\delta_a},  \frac{M}{\delta_a} \right) < \infty$$
Since $\max (\delta_a,\delta_b) >0$ because $a \neq b$.

First let us take $n > N$ such that $|a_n-a| < \epsilon_a$, $|b_n-b| < \epsilon_b|$ and $|c_n-c|< \epsilon_c$. We set $u_n = d_n -d$, and we take $D$ such that $\forall n,\, d_n < D$ this gets us:
$$\begin{align*}
0 &= a_n d_{n+1} +b_n d_n -c_n\\
& = (a_n-a) d_{n+1}+a d_{n+1} + (b_n-b) d_n + bd_n -(c_n-c) -c\\
&= (a_n-a) d_{n+1}+a u_{n+1} + ad + (b_n-b) d_n + bu_n +bd -(c_n-c) -c\\
&= a u_{n+1} + b u_{n} + (a_n-a) d_{n+1} + (b_n-b) d_n -(c_n-c) + (ad+bd-c)\\
&=  a u_{n+1} + b u_{n} + (a_n-a) d_{n+1} + (b_n-b) d_n -(c_n-c)
\end{align*}$$
So we get:
$$u_{n+1} = -\frac{b}{a} u_{n}  - \frac{1}{a}\left((a_n-a) d_{n+1} + (b_n-b) d_n -(c_n-c) \right)$$

We can already do the case $a=0$ because it gives us
$$ b u_{n} =\left( (a_n-a) d_{n+1} + (b_n-b) d_n -(c_n-c)\right) \to 0$$
So $u_n \to 0$ thus $d_n \to d$.

Now we suppose $a \neq 0$, with the right choice our our epsilons we get
$$-\frac{b}{a} u_{n} - \epsilon_N\leqslant u_{n+1} \leqslant -\frac{b}{a} u_{n} + \epsilon_N$$
Iterating these inequalities, we get
$$\left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)^k u_{n} - \epsilon_N \left( \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^i \right) \leqslant u_{n+k} \leqslant \left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)^k u_{n} + \epsilon_N \left( \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^i \right) $$
Which gives:
$$\left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)^k u_{n} - \frac{1-\frac{b^k}{a^k}}{1-\frac{b}{a}}\epsilon_N  \leqslant u_{n+k} \leqslant \left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)^k u_{n} + \frac{1-\frac{b^k}{a^k}}{1-\frac{b}{a}}\epsilon_N $$

Now since $u_n$ is bounded, we can deduce that if $b<a$, for $\epsilon>0 $ and for $N,K$ well chosen, for all $n \geqslant N+K$
$$-\epsilon \leqslant u_n \leqslant \epsilon$$
Which means that $u_n \to 0$ and thus $d_n \to d$.

Now let us consider the case $b > a > 0$ we define $\gamma = \frac{b}{a}$.
Suppose that $u_n$ does not converge to $0$, this means that $\exists \eta >0$ such that $\forall N > 0, \, \exists n \geqslant N$ such that $|u_n| >\eta$. Since we can chose some $N$ such that $\epsilon_N = \frac{\eta (\gamma-1)}{2}$, and from this $N$ we choose one suitable $n$ verifying the latter property.
We already had
$$(-\gamma)^k u_{n} - \frac{\gamma^k-1}{\gamma-1}\epsilon_N  \leqslant u_{n+k} \leqslant (-\gamma)^k u_{n} + \frac{\gamma^k-1}{\gamma-1}\epsilon_N $$
Hence
$$\begin{eqnarray}
u_{n+k}& \geqslant & (-\gamma)^k u_{n} - \frac{\gamma^k-1}{\gamma-1}\epsilon_N \\
-u_{n+k} &\geqslant & -(-\gamma)^k u_{n} - \frac{\gamma^k-1}{\gamma-1}\epsilon_N  
\end{eqnarray}$$
From this we deduce:
$$\begin{align*}
|u_{n+k}| &\geqslant \gamma^k |u_n| - \frac{\gamma^k -1}{\gamma-1} \epsilon_N \\
&\geqslant  \gamma^k \left(\eta - \frac{\epsilon_N}{\gamma-1}\right)\\
&= \gamma^k \frac{\eta}{2} \to \infty
\end{align*}$$
This means that $u_n$ is unbounded hence it is absurd and $u_n \to 0$.



I think that using your observation about the $a=0$ case I was able to solve the problem using limit inferior and limit superior, I will start writing it down now.

@QuantumBoy I hope it works!

I am not really sure it works. My idea was to take a subsequence $(d_{n_k})$ of $(d_n)$ that converges to $\displaystyle l_=\liminf_{n\to \infty} d_n$ and then if we take the limit inferior in the equality $a_{n_k}d_{n_k+1}+b_{n_k}d_{n_k}=c_{n_k}$ we have $\displaystyle c=bl_+\liminf_{k\to \infty}(a_{n_k}d_{n_k+1})$ and since we now have $a>0$ we get $\displaystyle  c=bl_+a\liminf_{k\to\infty}d_{n_k+1}$. But it is not necessarily true that $\displaystyle \liminf_{k\to\infty}d_{n_k+1}=l_$, right?

eah extracted sequences don’t work well with recursion relations. However I think I have the end of the proof

indeed, extracted sequences and recurrences are nasty. I read your edit, I believe that this is indeed correct and this finishes the proof, thank you so much. I only have two questions to make sure I really understand this: 1. Why isn't the case $a_n=a$, $b_n=b$ and $c_n=c$ with $b>a$ a counterexample as you initially said? After you said that I was also quite convinced that this is a counterexample. 2. The inequality $|u_{n+k}| \ge \gamma^k |u_n| - \frac{\gamma^k -1}{\gamma-1} \epsilon_N$ comes from the previous estimate and the fact that $u_n>0$, right?

@QuantumBoy Only the previous estimate in fact you don’t necessarily have $u_n >0$

@juio_es_sui_glace I thought that we also need that $u_n>0$ to be able to write $|u_n|$ in the previous estimate, can we replace $u_n$ by its absolute value in some other way?

No you don’t need it, if you want I can add an extra step

that would be awesome, thank you! What about my other question, why isn't that a counterexample?

It is not a counterexample because if you have such sequences then $d_n$ does not verify positiveness

oh right, silly me. Thank you!

@QuantumBoy explanation added

thank you so much for everything, now it is absolutely clear!
